# Unable to cast object of type ListItem to String

Tags: c#, web-services, loops

I am trying to remove specific items from a ListBox however I am getting a cast error.
It does not seem to like the fact I have referred to the items in the ListBox as `string` items.

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            foreach (string item in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
                int flag = ws.callFlags(10, item); 

                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Error** -

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.String'.
```

How can I resolve this?

**EDIT**

My problem being when I change to the method of `(ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)`(which I had tried) the line - `int flag = ws.callFlags(10, item);` breaks because the web service is looking to receive a `string` specifically. This then gives the error -

```
Error   2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'string'
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'testFrontEnd.WebService1.callFlags(int, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: Use `ListItem` instead of `string`.

Comment: See edit as I had already tried to implement this, the problem is that the web service is requiring a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating over `ListItems`, so you should do:

```
foreach( ListItem item in ListBox1.Items){
    WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
    int flag = ws.callFlags(10, item.Text); // <- Changed to item.Text from item

    if (flag == 1)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(item); // <- You'll have an issue with the remove
    }
}
```

You're also going to get an error when you attempt to `Remove` an `Item` from the `ListBox` because you are not allowed to remove from an `Enumerable` that you are iterating over. Naively, you can switch your `foreach` loop to a `for` loop to solve that issue.

This code should work to remove as well as fix your "Unable to cast" error.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListItem item = ListBox1.Items[i];
    WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
    int flag = ws.callFlags(10, item.Text);

    if (flag == 1)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(item); 
    }
}
```

A final note; your `WebService1` seems to be a custom class, it might be a good idea to have it implement the `IDisposable` interface and wrap it in a `using` clause so that you can be sure that it is properly disposed after use.

```
public class WebService1 : IDisposable { // ... 

using (WebService1 ws = new WebService1())
{ 
    // Code from inside your for loop here
}
```

Comment: This seems very close and is a very well thoght out answer however for some reason about half the list is clearing? Even though for debugging purposes I have set only two records to be '-1' in the database, so should on leave 2 records in the listbox? I will mark this as correct if I can get it to work however right now the result is rather odd.

Comment: Ok I have just realised that if I press it once, half of them delete, it I uncheck then check again another half go, if I repeat this eventually I get down to the two remain '-1' rows!! So it does kind of work, however have you any idea why I need to repeatedly push it until all unwanted values are gone?!

Comment: @Jambo It is difficult to tell you what is wrong without knowing what  the `callFlags` method does. Since you check the returned value against `1` (`if (flag == 1)`) you are removing every item where the call to `callFlags` returns `1`. Perhaps you want to check just that it isn't equal to `-1`? Something like (`if (flag != -1)`).

Comment: ok, i tried that and it has the same functionality, its odd however your code has done what it is meant to in terms of removing the items from the list.

Answer (score 3):

Change your remove to be:

```
ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items.FindByName(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

ListBox1.Items returns a collection of `ListItem` objects.  You want to have `item` be of type `ListItem` and then use `item.Text`, or possibly `item.Value`.